# a method like delete & update that runs on multiple records?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How can I code a method in model that I use it for multiple records like delete or update?

```
User::whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])->delete();
```

My method is like this:

```
public function remove()
{
    $this->update([
        'expired_at' => now()->addYear()
    ]);
}
```

But above method can update one record and I can't use :

```
User::whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])->remove();
```

I try this

```
public function remove()
{
    $this->update([
        'expired_at' => now()->addYear()
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Try to cut up your questions in 2 questions, you're asking 2 things at once. You want to delete multiple records, correct? Then ... just to `debug` your code, first do a select. What comes from your select with `now()->addYear()`, will it give you records, then you can easily delete those records, yes

Comment: The issue is that you are using `$this` which affects only a single (eloquent model?) instance. There's not enough context here to know how this is used in practice and what solutions will actually work for your code unless you provide a more end-to-end description of what you are doing

Answer (score 3):

This is how you can do it based on the `destroy()` function in laravel-9 model:

**User Model (Add):** (change line 31 accordingly)

```
/**
 * Update the models for the given IDs.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Support\Collection|array|int|string  $ids
 * @return int
 */
public static function remove($ids)
{
    if ($ids instanceof EloquentCollection) {
        $ids = $ids->modelKeys();
    }

    if ($ids instanceof BaseCollection) {
        $ids = $ids->all();
    }

    $ids = is_array($ids) ? $ids : func_get_args();

    if (count($ids) === 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    // We will actually pull the models from the database table and call update on
    // each of them individually so that their events get fired properly with a
    // correct set of attributes in case the developers wants to check these.
    $key = ($instance = new static)->getKeyName();

    $count = 0;

    foreach ($instance->whereIn($key, $ids)->get() as $model) {
        //Do your update query here
        if ($model->update(['expired_at' => now()])) {
            $count++;
        }
    }

    return $count;
}
```

**Controller call:**

```
//List of model IDs
User::remove([2, 3, 4, 5, 6]);
```

Alternatively if you just want to update directly without creating extra logics, **you can always just call like this:**

```
User::whereIn('id', [6, 7])->update(['expired_at' => now()]);
```

But if you want to handle complex operations like comparing dates, changing records and other things, then modify the foreach loop according to your needs.

Comment: I don't want to get any Ids parameter and I need a dynamically method

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
public function remove($ids)
{
    User::whereIn('id', $ids)->update([
        'expired_at' => now()->addYear()
    ]);
}
```

And Id's array

```
$ids = [1, 2, 3];
User::remove($ids);
```

Comment: but I don't want to get Ids parameter like delete() method

Comment: @HamedAlizade didn't get you

Comment: I want to code a non-static method in the User model that will be executed on the filtered model which may be a record.

like:

$users = User::where('status', 2);
$user->myMethod();

Comment: The example by abudlla and my example above, both accomplish exactly what your original question was asking. Are you asking for another question??

Comment: No, I'm explaining my question more.
I don't need a static method that give a parameter as the model ids.